# Ignore the set method of a value in p:inputText until the form is submitted

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Anyone know of a way to assign the value of a p:inputText so it displays correctly in a dialog window but only update a change in the value from a commandButton action instead of a dynamic set method of the value in the backing bean. Have the users add a step and it shows up in the ring then they can click the individual steps, but I want them to be able to update the step info only through the update step button, not by just changing the field and closing the dialog? Built-in method would be prefer, I know I can code around, but trying not to.

Thanks in advance....

```
    <p:ajaxStatus onstart="statusDialog.show();" onsuccess="statusDialog.hide();"/>  

    <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog" header="Status"   
        draggable="false" closable="false">  
        <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/ajaxloadingbar.gif" />  
    </p:dialog> 

    <h:form id="form">

    <p:panel  header="Setup System" >

        <p:selectOneMenu  value="#{groups.selected_sys_code}" id="systems" rendered="#{utility.systemDD}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choose System" itemValue="" />  
            <f:selectItems value="#{supportBean.access_system_codes}"/>
            <p:ajax  listener="#{groups.valueChanged}" event="valueChange" render="systemForm" execute="@all"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>  

        <h:panelGroup id="systemForm" > 
         <p:panel id="panel" header="Step Details">  

            <p:messages id="msgs"/>   

            <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label, value" styleClass="grid">  
                  <p:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="veaGrid"> 
                     <h:outputLabel for="name" value="Name:"/>                        
                        <p:inputText id="name" value="#{setup.name}" label="Name"  required="true"/>        
                     <h:outputLabel for="desc" value="Description:"/>                 
                        <p:inputText id="desc" value="#{setup.description}" label="Description" required="true"/>
                     <h:outputLabel for="email" value="Email For Group Responsible:"/> 
                        <p:inputText id="email" value="#{setup.emailResp}" label="Email"  required="true"/> 
                     <h:outputLabel for="process" value="Process:"/>                      
                        <p:inputText id="process" value="#{setup.process}" label="Process"  required="true"/>
                  </p:panelGrid>
            </h:panelGrid>  

            <p:commandButton value="Add Step" update="panel,stepsRing" actionListener="#{setup.setSteps}" process="@form"  >

            </p:commandButton>
            <p:commandButton value="Submit All Steps" actionListener="setup.submitSteps">

            </p:commandButton>
        </p:panel>
        </h:panelGroup>
        <h:panelGroup id="stepsRing" >

               <p:panel header="Steps">
                     <p:ring id="basic" value="#{setup.steps}" var="step" >  
                        <p:column> 
                        <p:outputPanel/> 
                          <p:outputPanel style="text-align:center;" layout="block"  >  
                              Step #{step.sequence}
                              <br/>
                               <p:commandButton update=":form:detail"  title="View" oncomplete="dlg.show()" value="Details" >  
                                    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{step}" target="#{setup.selectedStep}" />  
                               </p:commandButton>   
                          </p:outputPanel>  
                        </p:column>  
                      </p:ring>        
               </p:panel> 
        </h:panelGroup>

 <p:dialog id="dialog" widgetVar="dlg" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" modal="true" width="300" >  

    <p:outputPanel id="detail" style="text-align:center;" layout="block">  

        <h:panelGrid  columns="2" cellpadding="5" rendered="#{not empty setup.selectedStep}">  
            <f:facet name="header">  
               Step #{setup.selectedStep.sequence}
            </f:facet>  

            <h:outputText value="Name: " />  
            <p:inputText id="name2" value="#{setup.selectedStep.name}" />  

            <h:outputText value="Description: " />  
            <p:inputText id="desc2" value="#{setup.selectedStep.description}" />  

            <h:outputText value="Email: " />  
            <p:inputText id="email2" value="#{setup.selectedStep.emailResp}"/>  

            <h:outputText value="Process: " />  
            <p:inputText id="process2" value="#{setup.selectedStep.process}"/>  

            <p:commandButton update="stepsRing" actionListener="#{setup.removeStep}" title="Remove" oncomplete="dlg.hide()" value="Remove Step"  >  
                  <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{step}" target="#{setup.selectedStep}" />  
            </p:commandButton>

            <p:commandButton update="stepsRing" process="@form" actionListener="#{setup.updateStep}" title="Update"  value="Update Step"  >  
                  <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{step}" target="#{setup.selectedStep}" />  
            </p:commandButton>  
        </h:panelGrid>  
    </p:outputPanel>  

</p:dialog>  


    </p:panel>
    </h:form>
```

BackingBean

```
@ManagedBean(name="setup")
@ViewScoped 
public class WorkStepSetupSystemBean implements Serializable{


private WorkSetup step;
public ArrayList <WorkSetup> steps=new ArrayList <WorkSetup> (); 
private WorkSetup ws;
private String system="test1";
private String emailResp;
private String process;
private String name;
private String description;
private Integer sequence;   

private String email2;
private String process2;
private String name2;
private String desc2;

private WorkSetup selectedStep;     

public WorkStepSetupSystemBean(){


}

public String getDesc2() {
    return desc2;
}
public String getEmail2() {
    return email2;
}
public String getName2() {
    return name2;
}
public String getProcess2() {
    return process2;
}

public  WorkSetup getSelectedStep() {
    return selectedStep;
}
public ArrayList<WorkSetup> getSteps() {
    return steps;
}

public WorkSetup getStep() {
    return step;
}


public void setSteps(ActionEvent event) {
    step= new WorkSetup();

    step.setName(name);
    step.setEmailResp(emailResp);
    step.setDescription(description);
    step.setSystem(system);
    step.setProcess(process);

    step.setSequence(steps.size()+1);
    steps.add(step);

    return;
}
public void setStep(ArrayList<WorkSetup> steps) {
    this.steps = steps;
}

public Integer getSequence() {
    return sequence;
}   
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public String getEmailResp() {
    return emailResp;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public String getProcess() {
    return process;
}
public String getSystem() {
    return system;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
public void setEmailResp(String emailResp) {
    this.emailResp = emailResp;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public void setProcess(String process) {
    this.process = process;
}
public void setSequence(Integer sequence) {
    this.sequence = sequence;
}
public void setSystem(String system) {
    this.system = system;
}
public void setDesc2(String desc2) {
    this.desc2 = desc2;
}
public void setEmail2(String email2) {
    this.email2 = email2;
}
public void setName2(String name2) {
    this.name2 = name2;
}
public void setProcess2(String process2) {
    this.process2 = process2;
}

public void setSelectedStep(WorkSetup selectedStep) {
    this.selectedStep = selectedStep;
}
public void removeStep(ActionEvent event) {

    steps.remove(steps.indexOf(this.selectedStep));
    for(int i=0;i<steps.size();i++){
        steps.get(i).setSequence(i+1);
    }

}
public void updateStep(ActionEvent event) {

    step=steps.get(steps.indexOf(this.selectedStep));
    step.setName(name2);
    step.setEmailResp(email2);
    step.setDescription(desc2);
    step.setSystem(system);

}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using

```
 <p:inplace id="inplaceName" > 
               <p:inputText id="name2" value="#{setup.selectedStep.name}" />  
               <p:tooltip for="inplaceName" value="Click here to edit"/> 
 </p:inplace>
```

without the AJAX option